# Why does apt-get's --reinstall option do nothing?

Tags: apt

I thought the `--reinstall` option was supposed to reinstall the specified packages. But when I invoke `sudo apt-get purge --reinstall <packagenames>`, `<packagenames>` are purged but not reinstalled. What is the correct usage of the option? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no such command as "--reinstall" for use with the "remove" or "purge" commands. You can use "--reinstall" in combination with the "install" command. such as "sudo apt-get install --reinstall packagename" to force a currently installed package to be reinstalled.

**How to uninstall and re-install a package:**

Step #1 = In terminal type "sudo apt-get purge packagename"

Step #2 = In terminal type "sudo apt-get install packagename"

**How To Uninstall (but leave config files) and re-install a package:**

Step #1 = In terminal type "sudo apt-get remove packagename"

Step #2 = In terminal type "sudo apt-get install packagename"

**How to Uninstall (and delete installer though keep dependency installers) and re-install a package:**

Step #1 = In terminal type "sudo apt-get purge packagename"

Step #2 = In terminal type "gksu nautilus", and browse to "/var/cache/apt/archives/" then delete the installer .deb file.

Step #3 = In terminal type "sudo apt-get install packagename"